# Finding limit of a function with root

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find the limit of this function and I'm not sure how to proceed
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt {x+3} -\sqrt x}{1-x} $$
I multiply by the conjugate
$$ \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sqrt {x+3} -\sqrt x}{1-x}*\frac{\sqrt {x+3} +\sqrt x}{\sqrt {x+3} +\sqrt x} $$
and I am left with
$$ \frac{ {x+3} - x}{(1-x)(\sqrt {x+3} +\sqrt x)} = \frac{3}{(1-x)(\sqrt {x+3} +\sqrt x)} $$
but after this I am stuck there is nothing to cancel and pluging in 1 will give me $\frac{3}{0}$

Thank you everybody it is much clearer now !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plug in $x=1$ in the beginning, you have the limit in the form $\frac{1}0$, which directly implies that the limit doesn't exist.

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}=-\infty\quad\mbox{and}\quad\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}=\infty$$

Here's a simple graph of the function $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt{x}}{1-x}$ drawn on Desmos.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This limit does not exist, since when $x\to 1$ from the left we get result $\infty $ and from the right $-\infty$.

Limit of the factor $\frac{3}{\sqrt {x+3} +\sqrt x} $ is $1$, but not exists for ${1\over 1-x}$ (draw this function) when $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is positive when $1-x>0\to x<1$ therefore
$$\underset{x\to 1^-}{\text{lim}}f(x)=+\infty;\;\underset{x\to 1^+}{\text{lim}}f(x)=-\infty$$
The two limits are different so the limit doesn't exist.